# Throwing an exception "Cannot convert from String to Char" while using String.replace

Tags: c#, string

So, I'm trying to remove a character from a string. I've been using [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) and it keeps throwing an exception. The exception says "Cannot convert from String to Char." This is my code:
`alphabet.Replace(alphabet[alphabetRed], String.Empty);`

I've already tried `Convert.ToChar(String.Empty);` and it still throws an exception.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put a small complete example.

Comment: how about `alphabet.Replace(alphabet[alphabetRed].ToString, String.Empty);`

Comment: That sounds like it's a compile-time error, not an exception. It's *really* important to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's cause `alphabet[alphabetRed]` will return a `char` and you are using `string.Empty` as replacement value. So either change it to

```
alphabet.Replace(alphabet[alphabetRed].ToString(), String.Empty);
```

(OR)

```
alphabet.Replace(alphabet[alphabetRed], '');
```

If you go through the MSDN documentation linked in you question, you will see `Replace()` has two overload where both arguments type must match

Comment: That fixed it. I feel really dumb for not thinking of that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The first argument for your method is acting as a char. You need to convert it to a string to make it work as `.Replace(String, String)`.

Try:  `alphabet.Replace(alphabet[0].ToString(), String.Empty);`